# PHP working with uneven numbers

Tags: php, arrays

I have two dynamic variables

```
$numberOfX = 2;
```

and

```
$numberOfY = 5;
```

The challenge for me is that I need to divide the number 5(`numberOfY`) between 2(`numberOfX`). That's an issue cause I will either through a calculation(divide) get a floating number like 2,5 or I can choose (ceil)  to round it up but then I get 3(and totally it will be more then 5, namely 6).

I need a whole integers with no decimals. But still it can't be more or less then 5.

So ideally I Would like an array e.g with 3 and 2 in it. As it added will give 5.

How can I do this in PHP , remembering that numberOfX and numberOfY can be any number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$numberOfX = 3;
$numberOfY = 5;

$result = array_fill(0, $numberOfX, (int) floor($numberOfY / $numberOfX)); 
$i = 0;
while (array_sum($result) !== $numberOfY) { 
    $result[$i++]++;
}
var_dump($result, array_sum($result));
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/tS3nd1)

Answer (score 0):

```
$numberOfX = 2;
$numberOfY = 5;
$intDivisionValues[] = intval($numberOfY/$numberOfX);
$intDivisionValues[] = $numberOfY - intval($numberOfY/$numberOfX);
```

$intDivisionValues will then be:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 2
   [1] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear about the algorithm you are looking for. I *guess* this might come close:

```
<?php

$numberOfX = 2;
$numberOfY = 5;

$full = intval($numberOfY / $numberOfX);
$part = intval($numberOfY % $numberOfX);

$output = array_fill(1, $numberOfX-1, $full);
$output[] = $full+$part;

var_dump($output);
```

The output for the example values would be:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  int(2)
  [1] =>
  int(3)
}
```

For an example using different values, especially different values for `$numberOfX` the result would be different, obviously. Here the output for values 3 and 31:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  int(10)
  [1] =>
  int(10)
  [2] =>
  int(11)
}
```

You can play around with other values to see if that suits your needs...

This algorithm behaves different to what @WilliamJanoti suggests in his answer. As said: your question is not really clear in what you are looking for...